# Access string resources and shared preferences from custom java class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my Android activity I am trying to construct a custom java class `WordPressRestApiHandler` like so:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ...
    private final WordPressRestApiHandler wordPressRestApiHandler = new WordPressRestApiHandler(LoginActivity.this, service);
    ...
```

In that class I would like to have access to the string resources and shared preferences. That is why I used `LoginActivity.this` as input. This is the constructor of my custom class:

```
protected WordPressRestApiHandler(Context initiateContext, OAuth10aService initiateService) {
    context = initiateContext;
    service = initiateService;

    int some = R.string.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY;
    String test = context.getString(some);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(test,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ...
```

I am able to get the integer some and its value is correct, but I am not able to access the string resource in the next line. logcat tells me:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:86)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal(ContextThemeWrapper.java:127)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:121)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:549)
at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:476)
at com.example.my_app.WordPressRestApiHandler.<init>(WordPressRestApiHandler.java:40)
at com.example.my_app.LoginActivity.<init>(LoginActivity.java:35)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

In this workflow the variable `test` will contain the unique identifier for my sharedPreferences file. Therefore it would look like `"com.example.PREFERENCE_FILE"`.

So far I have tried several methods like calling `App.getContext().getString()` for a custom activity `App` or handling over `this` (therefore an object of type `AppCombatActivity`) but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how you can't access the string resource test?  Will the code not compile, or do you get an exception, or something else? What's in strings.xml for PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY?

Comment: @tim.paetz thanks for your response! I updated my post in order to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the variable wordPressRestApiHandler in onCreate() method.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ...
    private WordPressRestApiHandler wordPressRestApiHandler;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        wordPressRestApiHandler = new WordPressRestApiHandler(LoginActivity.this, service);
    }
}
```